# Copy "const" constructor - linker error?

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following programme is just meant to try out the inheriting and the following code works great... until I add "const" to the copying constructor in the inheriting class "pochodna" without changing anything. This makes the code change in the following way (ofc, the change has also been done in the header file):

```
pochodna::pochodna(const pochodna & wzor): podstawowa(wzor) {
    this->x=wzor.x;
    this->y=wzor.y;
}
```

The compiler displays the following error after the change:

`[Linker error] undefined reference to pochodna::pochodna(pochodna&)` .

The same happens when I add "const" to the operator= argument making it podstawowa& operator=(**const** podstawowa& obiekt). Can you tell me why this happens? :)

One of the classes podstawowa.h:

```
#ifndef PODSTAWOWA_H
#define PODSTAWOWA_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class podstawowa
{
private: 
    int alfa;
    int beta;
    const int staly;
public:
    podstawowa(int=0, int=0);
    podstawowa(const podstawowa& wzor);
    ~podstawowa();
    podstawowa& operator=(podstawowa& obiekt);
    ostream& operator<<(ostream &strumien);
};

#endif // PODSTAWOWA_H
```

Podstawowa.cpp

```
#include "podstawowa.h" // class's header file
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


podstawowa::podstawowa(int alf,int bet): alfa(alf), beta(bet),staly(0)
{}

podstawowa::podstawowa(const podstawowa& wzor):staly(0){
this->alfa = wzor.alfa;
this->beta = wzor.beta;

                               }

podstawowa::~podstawowa()
     {}


podstawowa& podstawowa::operator=( podstawowa& obiekt){
        this->alfa = obiekt.alfa;
        this->beta = obiekt.beta;
        return *this;
        }


ostream& podstawowa::operator<<(ostream &strumien){
 strumien << "Alfa: ";
 strumien << this->alfa;
 strumien << "\n";
 strumien << "Beta: ";
 strumien << this->beta;
 strumien << "\n";
 return strumien;
 }
```

Another class, inheriting from podstawowa: pochodna.h

```
#ifndef POCHODNA_H
#define POCHODNA_H

#include "podstawowa.h" 
class pochodna : public podstawowa
{   private:
double x;
double y;
public:
    pochodna(double=0, double=0);
    pochodna(pochodna&);
    ~pochodna();
    pochodna& operator=(pochodna&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, pochodna&);
};

#endif // POCHODNA_H
```

pochodna.cpp

```
#include "pochodna.h" // class's header file

pochodna::pochodna(double iks, double ygr):podstawowa(), x(iks),y(ygr)
{}
pochodna::pochodna(pochodna & wzor): podstawowa(wzor) {

                        this->x=wzor.x;
                        this->y=wzor.y;
                        }


pochodna::~pochodna()
{}


pochodna& pochodna::operator=(pochodna& obiekt){
      (*this).podstawowa::operator=(obiekt);
      this->x=obiekt.x;
      this->y=obiekt.y;
      }

ostream& operator<<(ostream& strumien, pochodna& obiekt){
     obiekt.podstawowa::operator<<(strumien); 
     strumien << "X: " << obiekt.x << "\nY: " << obiekt.y <<"\n";
     return strumien;
     }
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "podstawowa.h"
#include "pochodna.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

pochodna pierwsza;
pochodna druga(0.123, 3.14);
cout << pierwsza << druga;
pierwsza = druga;
cout << "Po pierwsza = druga: \n";
cout << pierwsza << druga;
pochodna enta(druga);
cout<< "teraz enta \n" << enta;
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: *Sigh* and that's why writing code in your native language is a bad idea. Anyway, please try to narrow the scope a bit (make an SSCCE). Try to isolate just the problem you have without all the unnecessary cruft.

Comment: Reverse polish notation: `{} Foo~ default Foo = Foo class`.

Comment: Please spend some time *reading* on this website before you post. Check out what other posts look like, and what distinguishes successful questions from unsuccessful ones. Read the FAQ, make some short examples, and then post something concise.

Comment: I pasted all the code together in http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php and it runs fine, are you sure you build it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to perform a clean before recompiling?

Comment: Don't "using namespace std;" in a header file, this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You modified function definition to take another type of argument ( const pochodna& ) while your function declaration ( the one in header file ) is still (pochodna&) . This makes two completely different functions. So that is why linker complaining about the lack of function body pochodna(pochodna&).
Simply add const to your header function definition to fix the problem.

Comment: *(ofc, the change has also been done in the header file)* He states that he changed that.

Comment: Well, then probably we need to see full code listing with the 'const' modifications being done everywhere. Because no matter what topic-starter tells, i see in his code non-const declaration pochodna(pochodna&); and linker error which tells me the same.

Comment: I agree it sounds like a dumb mistake.